# Global Filters on a Multitenancy Application with EF Core 6 + GraphQL on a single database approach

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, graphql

how have you been?

Can someone help us with these multi-tenancy questions and best practices with EF Core 6.0?

We are working on a multi-tenancy application exposing data through a GraphQL endpoint. We are running with .NET 5.0, EF Core 6, GraphQL and SQL Server.

[image: Approach]

Our setup is running fine. There are more than 45 tenants on this solution, and each Tenant has their Web Application that connects on a single GraphQL endpoint. The only thing that changes for each Tenant is the data, that is logically separated by a "TENANT_ID" column.

The approach and pattern that we decided for use in this project is based on a shared database with no schema customization (only dbo). In resume: One database, one schema, one GraphQL endpoint and multiple websites consuming these services. Websites that connect on the GraphQL need to pass a JWT and a Tenant ID. This field "TenantID" passed in the header is used for allowing the filter on the server side.

Example: Advertises.Where(a => a.TenantID == x);

We are studying the best practices to filter the data based on a TENANT_ID passed from the client to the server using some HTTP headers.

EF Core 6 has the Global Query Filters, but it seems is not possible to apply the filter, because the TenantID changes for every requisition.

The EF Core OnModelCreating method is always called once per AppDomain per DbContext, but we need to change this value for every request.

Does anyone recommend an approach to apply EF Query Filters using a external ID came from a http request?

In our research, we found some tips to inject the IHttpContextAccessor on the database layer (thus, to retrieve the headers, and apply the filters based on the TenantID), but, I confess that I'm not confortable for using the AspNetCore.Http namespace on the database layer.

Thank you all.

Answer (score -1):

Claims are the way.

After some research, we found out that through the query type operations, it's possible to receive a ClaimsPrincipal object, a class from the System.Security.Claims namespace.

Therefore, it is possible to send some HTTP headers that contain your Tenant ID. This value could be your KEY for filtering. In my case, that was a Guid type.

In this sample, we are passing an object called "claims" which is a ClaimsPrincipal.

```
    [Authorize(Policy = "YourPolicyName"), UseDbContext(typeof(YourDatabaseContext)), UseOffsetPaging, UseFiltering, UseSorting]
    public IQueryable<User> Users(ClaimsPrincipal claims, [Service] YourDatabaseContext context)
    {
        var tenantID = claims.Get(ClaimTypes.GroupSid);

        return context.Users.Where(u => u.TenantID == tenantID);
    }
```

After that, we just needed to create a extension method to retrieve data from the Claim:

```
public static class ClaimsExtensions
{
    public static Guid Get(this ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal, string claimType)
    {
        var element = claimsPrincipal.FindFirstValue(claimType);

        if (element is not null)
        {
            if (Guid.TryParse(element, out Guid id))
                return id;
        }

        return Guid.Empty;
    }
}
```

That's it. Don't forget it is needed to pass the SID on your HTTP Request.

Comment: where is your global filter here tho? So you gave up on "OnModelCreating" in your dbcontext then?